# Shopify one page checkout tracking in GA4

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, enhanced-ecommerce

i want to track the checkout performance of my shopify shop via google analytics 4. Usually there are the steps "begin_checkout", "add_shipping_info" and "add_payment_info". Those are pushed into the dataLayer with the item array with each page separately.

Having the new one page checkout i want to push those events, for example "add_shipping_info" when someone filled in all the contact information that is needed in the form.

So far i am not quite sure how to track add_payment_info since a payment method is already preselected. Otherwise you could push this event on click with the associated payment method...

Is there anyone who encountered the same issue and is there already someone who got a solution?

Thank you <3

Comment: You should follow this guide for the new event tracking https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/pixels/custom-pixels/code

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom pixel you should be able to subcribe to the shopify analytics events and pass them to GA.

Intro to custom pixels:
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/pixels/custom-pixels/code

All available events:
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/web-pixels-api/standard-events